# Python Locking the mouse and keyboard

Tags: python, pynput

I am writing a code in which I need to lock the user's input via mouse and keyboard.
I am using sockets and when i get the message "LOCK" it should lock the computer and when I get the message "UNLOCK" it will unlock the user's PC.
I've tried using the module pyhook but if I use this module then the program will stop and I cant receive info from the socket. I have also tried working with pynput but I couldn't find a way to lock the keyboard/ mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a windows machine, you can use `LockWorkstation()`from `ctypes`

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation ()
```

if you are on an ubuntu machine, you can do the following.

```
os.popen('gnome-screensaver-command --lock')
```